# ActionBarSherlock pulldown menu with tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement ActionBarSherlock with tabs but allow a pulldown menu in the action bar on certain tabs.  I've read that the only way to get both is to create a custom actionProvider for the pulldown.  Here is the code I wrote to implement:

menu_with_dropdown.xml (with a separate overflow menu that is working fine)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/motivate_picker"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Right Here"
        android:actionProviderClass=".ActionBarSpinner">

    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_bar_plus_icon">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_1"
                  android:title="@string/menu_1" />
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_2"
                  android:title="@string/menu_2" />
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_3"
                  android:title="@string/menu_3"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/menu_4"
                  android:title="@string/menu_4"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

The tab fragment that uses this pulldown inflates it here

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    menu.clear();
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_with_dropdown, menu);

}
```

ActionBarSpinner.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.SubMenu;

public class ActionBarSpinner extends ActionProvider implements
        MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    Context context_;

    public ActionBarSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        context_ = context;


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView() {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context_);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_menu,null);

        //return view;  //Will have formatted pulldown but not register clicks for submenu    
        return null;  //Will register clicks and expand submenu but not be formatted as desired
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPerformDefaultAction() {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasSubMenu() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu subMenu) {
        MenuItem item = subMenu.add("Test1");
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        item = subMenu.add("Test3");
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

        item = subMenu.add("Test2");
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

actionbar_menu.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/motivate_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Friend Picker"
    />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/switcher_arrow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So the problem arises when I call onCreateActionView() in ActionBarSpinner.  If I return the inflated View of actionbar_menu.xml, it never expands the subMenu that I created.  If I return null in onCreateActionView(), the submenu expands when I click on it but it doesn't have the custom layout I made (it actually shows nothing).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return null in order for the onPrepareSubMenu() being called.

Then, all these setups in onCreateActionView() need to go in to onCreateOptionsMenu() in probably MainActivity.

For example,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    // Override the default language icon to the language is being used
    MenuItem mI = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_locale);
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    String locLan = locale.getLanguage();

    if (locLan.equals(Locale.CHINESE.getLanguage())) {
        mI.setIcon(R.drawable.insready);
    } else if (locLan.equals(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage())) {
        mI.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_locale_en);
    } else if (locLan.equals(Locale.FRENCH.getLanguage())) {
        mI.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    }

    return true;
}
```